# Show back button even if no pages are in back stack

Tags: win-universal-app, template10

I'm making a Master/Details app with Template 10. The Master/Details Template 10 sample uses a CommandBar to get full control over when the back button is shown, but I'd like to show the back button on a PageHeader or on the shell. The problem is, since there is no back stack, the button refuses to be shown. How should I handle this?

Answer (score 2):

Override the OnNavigatedTo event and set AppViewBackButtonVisibility to Visible in the code-behind file for each page that you want to enable the title bar back button.

Take a look here: http://grogansoft.com/blog/?p=1116

The important part is `"AppViewBackButtonVisibility"`

```
if (rootFrame.CanGoBack)
{
    // Show UI in title bar if opted-in and in-app backstack is not empty.
    SystemNavigationManager.GetForCurrentView().AppViewBackButtonVisibility = 
        AppViewBackButtonVisibility.Visible;
}
```

I also suggest you take a look at the AppBar properties.
Especially the Visibility which gets or sets the visibility of a UIElement and you could force the visibility of an item:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.appbar.aspx

Comment: I'm still having trouble getting the PageHeader's back button to show. Here's the code that runs when the app moves to a details view and I want to show the back button in the PageHeader:
`SystemNavigationManager.GetForCurrentView().AppViewBackButtonVisibility = AppViewBackButtonVisibility.Visible;
Template10.Common.BootStrapper.Current.ShowShellBackButton = false;
Template10.Common.BootStrapper.Current.UpdateShellBackButton();
Template10.Common.BootStrapper.Current.NavigationService.Refresh();`

Comment: I think your answer refers to standard UWP rather than the Template10 API. I'm also looking for a solution to this.

Answer (score 0):

So I've created a hacky solution to this. Basically I'm adding a dummy value onto the stack so that the back button thinks there is something to go back to.

```
var entry = new PageStackEntry(typeof(bool), null, null);
Frame.BackStack.Insert(0, entry);
```

Then I've added a `BootStrapper.BackRequested` event which sets `HandledEventArgs.Handled` to `true` so Template10 doesnt actually pop the page. That way I've got full control over the back stack and the back visibility.

Comment: I've registered the listener for BootStrapper.BackRequested, but BackRequested doesn't seem to occur when the PageHeader's back button is pressed... I've set a breakpoint at my handling method for BackRequested and it isn't hit, it just fails:

`at Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Frame.GoBack()
   at Template10.Services.NavigationService.FrameFacade.GoBack()
   at Template10.Services.NavigationService.NavigationService.GoBack()
   at Template10.Behaviors.NavButtonBehavior.Element_Click(Object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)`

Comment: I am using the most recent NuGet release of Template 10. Is this perhaps something that is fixed in the more recent GitHub code and hasn't been included in NuGet yet? I stumbled across this: https://github.com/Windows-XAML/Template10/issues/454

Comment: Disregard my previous comment; I updated to 1.1.4 released yesterday and now I can't click the PageHeader's back button at all. Hmm.

Comment: I'm running 1.1.3 and I had no problems with the event not being called